# How to change background color of table Column

Tags: sapui5

I have a Column in my table that has a grey bg color by default in sapui5. Is there any way I can change the background color? without using CSS?

Comment: not sure what you want to achive. You can use the alternateRowColors or highlight functionality of your ColumnListItem or use the valueState of your controls...

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not possible without using CSS and I also think that it is part of the design guidelines to either have the plain table background or the alternate row colors for the sap.ui.table.